# 502 Bad Gateway for nginx configuration that runs inside a docker container

Tags: nginx, deployment, docker-container, letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

[image: Current Nginx configuration]

I'm trying to deploy a web app using a VPS. I currently have two Docker containers, one is running Angular + Nginx (Angular is running on 4200) and the other is running the Spring Boot backend and the PostgreSQL. (Spring Boot is on port 8080). I generated a free certificate using Certbot and the containers run ok until I make a request to my page. I get 502. What could be the issue?

I tried changing the proxy pass localhost, https instead of http, the address of my VPS instead of localhost but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: When I've run certbot in an nginx environment, my nginx config file gets updated substantially with code they supply. Did you follow the [instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions)?

Comment: I guess my next step would be to figure out how to run sudo certbot --nginx from inside the docker container since i'm new to all of this. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Please show your nginx errror log.

Comment: For both the requests it sends the message is: Nginx connection refused while connecting to upstream